# Capacitor-Community:Sqlite update query not working and dbchanges returning zero

Tags: java, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am using `Capacitor-Community sqlite` for my AndroidApp.

**query:**

```
private String persistenceGetFileVersionUpdatequery(String fileName) {
        return "Update LastSync Set lastfileversion = 'Alter_V4';";
    }
```

Using method `execSQL` and return response is

```
{"changes":0}
```

how to solve above issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested the `execSQL` method but I'm using the `run` method which does work.